# Replace the first duplicated data in a row of dataframe with NA

Tags: r

I find that rows in my dataframe 'Data' often have the 1st element equal 2nd element. I want to replace this 1st element that is duplicated with NA and keep the 2nd element.

My dataframe 'Data' with 3 columns c1, c2 and c3 like this

```
c1 c2 c3
1  1  4
5  2  9
3  1  8
7  7  2
9  9  1
```

I tried to run this code

```
for (i in 1:length(Data)) {
Data[i,1]<- if (Data[i,1]==Data[i,2]) NA else Data[i,1]
}
```

but it doesn't work. I would like to use Data[i;1] instead of Data$c1[i] because i use loops of merge() to recreate my dataframe and the name of the columns change every time the dataframe is recreate.
I want to replace any value in column c1 which is duplicated in the same row of column c2 by NA, like this

```
c1 c2 c3
NA 1  4
5  2  9
3  1  8
NA 7  2
NA 9  1
```

Could you help me, please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Further to the answers below - always remember that R rarely requires a for-loop for basic things. Always try to think how you can vectorize what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much indeed. I'm new to R and I tend to think about everything in a much more complicated way than it actually is. I'm trying to make good that shortcoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df[df$c1 == df$c2, 1] <- NA

 c1 c2 c3
1 NA  1  4
2  5  2  9
3  3  1  8
4 NA  7  2
5 NA  9  1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you let me know how I use something of position to refer the element instead of the specific name for the column df$c1? Because the name of the columns change everytime df is recreated.

Comment: you can instead write then `df[,1] == df[,2]`.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much indeed for your fast and effective answer. Have a nice afternoon !

Comment: you could accept the answer, so the question appears as solved.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I accept your answer late. This is the first time i use this website and I didn't know how to accept the answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(c1=ifelse(c1==c2,NA,c1))
  c1 c2 c3
1 NA  1  4
2  5  2  9
3  3  1  8
4 NA  7  2
5 NA  9  1
```